# Drawing an arrow that follows the user's finger and connects two circles

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer

I have many circle views on a background view and I want to be able to tap a circle, drag from there to another circle and have an arrow drawn from the first circle to the next one.

The arrow needs to be live, I mean that it will start at the initial circle and end at the user's finger until the user lifts his or her finger. Then the arrow will stick to a second circle if there is one touching the arrow, or snap back to the initial circle if it doesn't touch any of the circles.

One can move the circles around and create new ones (this has already been done) and the arrows should follow.

I need the arrows to be manipulatable objects, I need to be able to count them and get their initial and ending points etc., so they can't just be drawn paths, they need to be some kind of resizing and rotating UIView subclass.

This is kind of like something you would see in vector drawing tools or mind map applications.

I couldn't quite get the arrow's butt to stay put while the arrow resizes and rotates, the line somehow gets wider sometimes as I move my finger and disappears sometimes. I know I'm not supposed to rely on the frame if the view is rotated, should I scale the arrow to make it longer? How would you implement such an arrow?

Also, how would architecture something like this? What I have now is an ArrowView, CircleView and a BackgroundView. The arrows and the circles handle their own touches and the background view will manage an array of arrows and circles.

I'm mainly looking for high level ideas and maybe code samples.

Comment: Have a look at `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. So you're saying I could set the ArrowView's `layerClass` to `CAShapeLayer` and then animate it's `path`? I would still need to resize and transform the view itself though.

Comment: You don't need to set the `layerClass`, just add a shape layer to your view's `layer` and change its path while you're dragging etc. There's no need to change the frame of the view.

Comment: So I can set the initial frame to anything and the path will get drawn outside of the view's frame.

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` (it's `NO` by default), you can have sublayers draw outside of the view's bounds.

Comment: It sounds like a really great solution, but this way I won't be able to handle touches to the arrow after I keave it.

Comment: If you need to handle touches, just make the view that contains the shape layers cover the whole screen/drawing area.